# Fourier Transform on positive real line

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Suppose $f(x)$ is defined only for $x\geq 0$. Is it correct to apply Fourier Transform operator to $f(x)$? I ask because integral of the Fourier Transform operator runs from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, but $f(x)$ is not defined for $x<0$.

P.S. Searching the net reveals examples where Fourier Transform operator is applied to partial differential equations defined over a semi-infinite domain, but that doesn't answer my question (or I don't know how it answers my question). Also I am an engineer and not a mathematician.

Comment: What is your function exactly? Can't you define your function equal to zero on $]-\infty,0]$? Notice that you must have either $\int |f(x)| dx< + \infty$ to apply directly the Fourier Transform.

Comment: You can settle for $\int|f(x)|^2dx<+\infty$ too, no? The Fourier transform can be extended to $L^2$ functions by a density argument if I remember correctly.

Comment: The natural transform to apply on the half line is the Laplace Transform. Typically Fourier transform is applied on the whole line and Fourier Series to finite intervals.

Comment: @Netchaiev My function in the simplest case is simply $e^{-x}$ defined over $x\geq 0$. It is the probability that a droplet does not suffer a collision after it has fallen a distance $x$ (oriented downward). Since a droplet falls and does not rise the probability function is not defined for $x<0$. Assuming it to be zero for $x<0$ is physically erroneous; it is simply not defined.

Comment: @TonyS.F. Please see my comment above.

Comment: @Paul I wish to decompose my function into a sine/cosine basis to employ some linearization arguments to simplify subsequent calculations. So you think Fourier transform is unconditionally inapplicable to my case?

Comment: @Deep you are right for the extension to $L^2$, but even it can be extended by density, it is not straightforward to compute the Fourier Transform. But in your case you are in $L^1$. Now, the important part is that you are wrong about your understanding of the density of the probability : since it is impossible for a droplet to rise, than the probability of such event is $0$, and the associated density on $]-\infty,0]$ is $0$. Your density is perfectly defined on $\mathbb{R}$ itself!

Comment: @Deep : the simple case of your problem is known as exponential distribution, and its Fourier Transform is $\frac{1}{1-it}$. (Again, it is not because an event is impossible that the density is not defined : on the contrary, that is precisely what a $0$ density means!)

Comment: @Netchaiev Thanks for your comment. You have given me food for thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also deal with the Fourier transform on $[0,\infty)$ through cosine and or sine transforms
$$
          \int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\cos(st)dt,\;\; \int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\sin(st)dt.
$$
Both of these have corresponding inverses:
$$
        \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\cos(st)dt\right) \cos(sx)ds \sim f(x), \\
        \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\sin(st)dt\right)\sin(sx)ds \sim f(x).
$$
Obviously there are problems with pointwise convergence at $x=0$ for the Fourier sine transform and its inverse sine transform. There are also issues for the cosine transform at $x=0$. But these are valid transforms in the $L^2$ sense, and the transforms are their own inverses, which is nice. There's also a Parseval $L^2$ identity for each.

Comment: +1 It seems that Cosine/Sine transforms are also defined over $(-\infty,+\infty)$ but for even (odd) functions the integral reduces to Cosine (Sine) transform over $[0,\infty)$ as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine_transforms.

Comment: @Deep : The Fourier sine transform also naturally arises in connection with the spectral theory for $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ on $[0,\infty)$ with $0$ endpoint condition at $x=0$. The cosine transform is associated with the same operator on $[0,\infty)$ but $0$ first derivative condition at $0$.